# Fetching value from oracle in the form like "4.57E+10"

Tags: oracle, exponential

I am fetching data from Oracle database and from one of the column fields I am getting a value like : "4.57E+10".
And I am trying to query the table with the same value but it is no able to fetch any value.
How can I convert this value to a suitable value so that I can fetch the value from the Oracle database.

Schema for table is like :
CUSTOMER_ID                NOT NULL NUMBER(38)

How to solve this?

Comment: use `SET numwidth 20`  or > 20 for higher values

Comment: yup it worked..!!